# android - place an image to the top of a transparent textview

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to work out a layout in android where an imageview is placed at the top of a text view with a transparent text and other text underneath. This is the code snippet of my attempt

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/writeups" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tips_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="tips_title"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tips_writeup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image"
            android:text="Tips writeups"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tips_share"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="SHARE"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tips_readmore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="READ MORE"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </LinearLayout></RelativeLayout>
```

Please how can I achieve the above from my attempt so far.

Comment: @parkercheck my ans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Use `LinearLayout` as your root layout and use attribute     `android:orientation="vertical"`.

**2.** Add `RelativeLayout` as a direct child of `LinearLayout` and place `ImageView` and tranparent `TextView` inside `RelativeLayout`. Use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to `TextView` to align it at the bottom of `ImageView`.

**3.** Add another `TextView` below `RelativeLayout` for `tips_writeup`.

**4.** For `Share` and `Read More`, use `LinearLayout` as container with attribute  `android:orientation="horizontal"`. Use `Button` with `style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"` instead of `TextView`.

**Update your layout structure as below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/dummy" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tips_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="Tips Title"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="#88000000"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tips_writeup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque pretium elit eu purus viverra, eu lobortis mi malesuada"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#727272"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tips_share"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SHARE"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tips_readmore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="READ MORE"
            android:textColor="#727272"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: Glad to know that. If my answer seems useful, I hope you will give an up-vote too.

Comment: it appears not to be clickable. the other demo I have is clickable. could anything be blocking the click events

Comment: Then you can use `TextView` for "SHARE" and "READ MORE".

Comment: is that what could be causing it. plz modify your answer

Comment: It will work with button but for this case you have add some extra code in your adapter. Better use TextView as you used earlier. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147076/discussion-between-parker-and-fat).

Answer (score 0):

For Textview

android:background="#CCD3D3D3"

For Answer

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/music"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/profilebanner" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Treating_cough"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Treating_cough text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:background="@color/black1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tips_writeup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tips writeups .............."
            android:textSize="15sp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tips_share"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:text="SHARE"
            android:textColor="@color/Blue"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tips_readmore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:text="READ MORE"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```